# Heatmap error "TraitError: The 'locations' trait of a Heatmap instance must be of length"

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a code that registers coordinates onto a heat map using Javascript on Jupyter Notebook. My code is:

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
gmaps.configure(api_key="MY API KEY")

data = [(-89.91161093276477, 35.241969778429194), (-89.87947624903887, 35.195319161704404), (-89.81418532101328, 35.17188216058175), (-89.75643652692003, 35.183538628834484), (-89.7496498284386, 35.14509890887518), (-89.78504762327763, 35.063349559432304), (-89.83100682136623, 35.013757847903044), (-89.85342496546569, 35.001086997562474)]
m = gmaps.Map()
heatmap_layer = gmaps.Heatmap(data=data)
m.add_layer(heatmap_layer)
m
```

But I keep on getting the error:

```
TraitError: The 'locations' trait of a Heatmap instance must be of length 1 <= L <= 9223372036854775807, but a value of [] was specified.
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because the function expects `locations` and you don't have anything defined there. I don't think you are calling your `heatmap_layer` correctly either.

https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#heatmaps

Try this:

```
import gmaps.datasets
gmaps.configure(api_key="MY API KEY")

locations = [(-89.91161093276477, 35.241969778429194), (-89.87947624903887, 35.195319161704404), (-89.81418532101328, 35.17188216058175), (-89.75643652692003, 35.183538628834484), (-89.7496498284386, 35.14509890887518), (-89.78504762327763, 35.063349559432304), (-89.83100682136623, 35.013757847903044), (-89.85342496546569, 35.001086997562474)]
m = gmaps.Map()
heatmap_layer = gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations)
m.add_layer(heatmap_layer)
m
```